# ffmpeg FLAC to AAC encoding

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding, flac, aac

I wanted to make sure that I'm not shooting myself in the foot and ask about this.
So currently I have an audio file in a .mkv container that looks like this

> Audio: FLAC (framed) 48000Hz stereo 1536kbps [A: Audio (flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16) [default]]
>
> ID                             : 2
> Format                         : FLAC
> Format/Info                    : Free Lossless Audio Codec
> Codec ID                       : A_FLAC
> Duration                       : 39mn 50s
> Bit rate mode                  : Variable
> Channel(s)                     : 2 channels
> Sampling rate                  : 48.0 KHz
> Bit depth                      : 16 bits
> Title                          : Audio
> Writing library                : libFLAC 1.2.1 (UTC 2007-09-17)

And I would like to convert it to AAC, preferably without losing the quality too much.
I did find a similar question asked on this forum.
But the method that was described there is about 3 years old.

In short:

> "compile your own ffmpeg for fdk_aac
> follow the AAC encoding guide and use fdk_aac's -vbr option - with a setting of 3"

Resulting in:

> ffmpeg -i input.flac -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 output.m4a".

By evilsoup. - taken from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77687/how-do-i-convert-flac-files-to-aac-preferrably-vbr-320k).

So I was wondering if this will work for my situation, or if it won't work for me.
If that's all it takes then no need to answer, and thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me. Notice that the vbr quality goes from 1 to 5, 5 being highest. What ends up as the appropriate level depends on source material and use. I suggest you play around with it a little.

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg supports two AAC-LC encoders:

- Native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`aac`)
- Fraunhofer FDK AAC (`libfdk_aac`)

FFmpeg supports one HE-AAC encoder:

- Fraunhofer FDK AAC (`libfdk_aac`)

## libfdk_aac

`libfdk_aac` is still the best AAC-LC encoder supported by FFmpeg, and is the only HE-AAC encoder supported by FFmpeg. However, its license is problematic when it comes to distribution, so you'll need to [compile `ffmpeg`](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) to be able to use it.

## Native FFmpeg AAC encoder

This encoder has seen many improvements since the [answer you refer to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77687/how-do-i-convert-flac-files-to-aac-preferrably-vbr-320k). It is [no longer considered experimental](http://ffmpeg.org/index.html#aac_encoder_stable), but it is not yet as good as `libfdk_aac`. However, if you give it enough bits it should be acceptable. The advantage of this encoder is that it is always available and comes with FFmpeg.

## Pipe

Not always practical, but you can pipe to your favorite, standalone encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i input -f wav - | fdkaac -I -m 5 - -o output.m4a
```

#### Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)

Comment: Just to flesh out your comment that the native encoder is not quite as good as Fraunhofer's, but acceptable at higher bit rates; listening test supporting that: https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,111085.0.html

Comment: Native encoder may be much enriched as of today, it might yield similar quality as fdk-aac.

Comment: @Quadcubic [Not according to kamedo2](https://twitter.com/kamedo2/status/1227925557309927426), a known ABX tester, but regardless I personally usually still use `-c:a aac`.

Comment: @llogan What about **vanilla AAC codec** + `-aac_coder twoloop`?

Comment: @tripulse I am not aware of any ABX tests involving anmr, twoloop, and fast. Would be interesting to see results. I can only suggest to give it a try.

Comment: TBH, FDK is kinda better than Vanilla. Also I'm recommending **AAC** with twoloop according to FFmpeg documentation that it uses a better algorithm than standard.